# Forbidden HTTPS request from Node.js server - what is going wrong here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, get

I'm attempting to make a GET request to the Discogs collection folders api via a node js server, however the request is 'Forbidden'.

At present, a html button triggers a GET request to the node server using fetch API. The Node server then routes the GET request to a handler which makes a https request to the GET collection folders endpoint.

I am expecting the following response (see 'Toggle' for the /users/{username}/collection/folders endpoint here):

[expected response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyGjb.png)
https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:user-collection,header:user-collection-collection

This requires authentication, for which a number of options are documented here: https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:authentication,header:authentication-discogs-auth-flow

I have made successful GET and POST requests by passing my api key as and Authorization header when making requests from the frontend using fetch api only, so I am attempting to use that method to authorize the request from the node server.

**Actual Output - Browser**

[Actual Output - Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCp1v.png)

**Actual Output - Node terminal**

[Actual Output - Node terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnr0A.png)

**HTML and Script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test GET request to Discogs API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Get Folders" onclick="getFolders()">
    </form>
    <script>
        async function getFolders() {
            try { 
                const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1000/getfolders')
                if(!res.ok) {
                    console.log('node server response not ok') 
                } else {
                    const jsonResponse = await res.json()
                    console.log('hello' + jsonResponse)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('there was an error' + error)
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Node js Server**

```
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const url = require('url')
const port = 1000
const username = 'someUsername'
const apiKey = 'apikey123456789'

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const {method} = req

    switch(method) {
        case 'GET':
            return handleGetRequest(req, res)
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unsupported request method: ${method}`)
    }

    })

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port:' + port);
})

const handleGetRequest = (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        hostname: 'api.discogs.com',
        path: `/users/${username}/collection/folders`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Discogs token=${apiKey}`
        }
    }

    const request = https.request(options, response => {
        let data = ''

        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk
        })

        response.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Retrieved Data:', data)
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)
            res.end(jsonData)
        })
    })

    request.end()
}
```

Comment: According to the docs https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:user-collection auth must be the oauth token flow so its likely `Discogs token=${apiKey}` is just your app key which wont work.

Comment: thanks for your response @LawrenceCherone - the docs also say that a user token can be used to access your own user account information (which is what I'm currently attempting), and outlines how to pass this as an Authorization header. I've made successful GET (and POST) requests to the same endpoint from the frontend using fetch api and passing my app key as an authorization header - is there a reason why this wouldn't work now I'm attempting the same, but this time from a node server?

Comment: read the docs *Retrieve a list of folders in a user’s collection. If the collection has been made private by its owner, authentication as the collection owner is required. If you are not authenticated as the collection owner, only folder ID 0 (the “All” folder) will be visible (if the requested user’s collection is public).* You MUST use https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:authentication,header:authentication-oauth-flow not https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:authentication,header:authentication-discogs-auth-flow read what it says directly under the titles

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - thanks again for your reply. I'm not sure how it explains things since my collection is not private and only 'Forbidden' is received in response to the node server's request. Why must the OAuth flow be used for authentication when under the heading https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:authentication,header:authentication-discogs-auth-flow it is stated _[...]you should use this authentication method as it is much simpler and is still secure._ and later says _Your other option is to send your credentials in the request as an Authorization header, as follows:[...]_ ?